# Append and request cookies in CORE 2 Razor page code-behind

Tags: razor-pages

In MVC CORE, this code will add a cookie from the code-behind and then read it into a variable

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        public IActionResult Index() {
            Response.Cookies.Append("key", "value");
            string cookieValueFromReq = Request.Cookies["key"];
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do the same in a Razor page.   I can do it in the Page itself like this

```
@{
    Response.Cookies.Append("key", "value");
}
```

but need to do it in the code-behind.   If I use it in code-behind which matches the MVC style like this

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace WebApplication1.ViewModel {
    public class BaseModel : PageModel {
       public BaseModel () {
            Response.Cookies.Append("key", "value");
       }
    }
}
```

`Response` is `null` so it crashes with a to-be-expected `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error.

Is it possible to read/write a cookie in Razor page code-behind and if so, how?
Do I need to force the initialisation of  `Response` or do something entirely different?

Comment: You can only do that after ASP.Net initializes the properties (not in the constructor)

Comment: BaseModel is by base ViewModel that each page can read containing the current user's name and the like. Is there a way to read a cookie in the BaseModel so the value can be passed to each Page or do I have to read the cookie (or call a method in the BaseModel) on each page individually?